# Parse XML from Clinicaltrials.gov

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse the primary endpoints from clinical trials.gov. I'm a little new to reading XML file which is where I'm sure I'm screwing up.

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

r = requests.get('https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies?expr=heart+attack')
root = etree.fromstring(r.content)

for child in root.iter('Field'):
    print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

I get:

```
Field {'Name': 'StartDate'}
Field {'Name': 'StartDateType'}
Field {'Name': 'PrimaryCompletionDate'}
Field {'Name': 'PrimaryCompletionDateType'}
Field {'Name': 'PrimaryOutcomeMeasure'}
Field {'Name': 'PrimaryOutcomeDescription'}
Field {'Name': 'PrimaryOutcomeTimeFrame'}
Field {'Name': 'CompletionDate'}...
```

So when I go back and try:

```
for child in root.iter('Field'):
    print(child.tag['Name'], child.attrib['PrimaryOutcomeMeasure'])
```

I get the below error:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-f201e3c2a2b1> in <module>
      9 
     10 for child in root.iter('Field'):
---> 11     print(child.attrib['PrimaryOutcomeMeasure'])

KeyError: 'PrimaryOutcomeMeasure'
```

What's going on?

Comment: Did you look at the file you get? "Name" is indeed an attribute of `Field` element. While 'PrimaryOutcomeMeasure' is the ***value*** of that attribute.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any research?

Comment: But that's why I'm confused - how do I get the value of "PrimaryOutcomeMeasure"? Every study in this XML should have a PrimaryOutcomeMeasure:

`<Struct Name="OutcomesModule">
            <List Name="PrimaryOutcomeList">
              <Struct Name="PrimaryOutcome">
                <Field Name="PrimaryOutcomeMeasure">In-hospital mortality of the patients with acute myocardial infarction in different-level hospitals across China</Field>
              </Struct>`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use an other library to write code, which is simple and readable.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
xml = req.get(
    'https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/query/full_studies?expr=heart+attack'
)
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
PrimaryOutcomeMeasure = doc.select('Field@Name="PrimaryOutcomeMeasure"')
print (PrimaryOutcomeMeasure.text)
# Or
PrimaryOutcome = doc.select('Struct@Name="PrimaryOutcome"')
print (PrimaryOutcome.select('Field@Name="PrimaryOutcomeMeasure"').text)
```

Result:

```
In-hospital mortality of the patients with acute myocardial infarction in different-level hospitals across China
In-hospital mortality of the patients with acute myocardial infarction in different-level hospitals across China
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples